# Replace Function Pointers with Functions

Tags: c, function-pointers, static-analysis, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

Which level is the best place to **do points-to analysis** and **replace** function pointers with real functions? **Frontend (Clang) or IR**?

Suppose that the points-to analysis is a simple heuristic based approach as follows:

1. Check for all **assignments** to a function pointer, and
2. Check for all **struct initializations** (the code is in C) that contain a function pointer.

Comment: I think I know what most of the words mean, but I'm not sure I can understand what you're asking.  It is very hard, in general, to replace calls via function pointer with calls directly to a function because one of the main reasons for using function pointers is to allow a pointer to point to different functions at runtime, which inherently means you can't replace the call-via-pointer with a direct call.  You'd have to prove that the function pointer is fixed once (initialization, or later assignment) and never changed thereafter.  That could be tricky without the whole program to review.

Comment: Yes. But you can think of the analysis as a semi-automated one. In the case of multiple candidates, I will choose the appropriate one based on the knowledge gained from profiling. The analysis is a context and flow insensitive may points-to analysis.